# how to replicate pytest paramterize decorator using pytest-case?

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest @pytest.mark.paramterize() decorator the argvalues can be a list for single arg or can be  a list of tuple for mulitple args. While in pytest-cases @parametrize_with_cases() the arg is nothing but the return value of case function.
**
I want to replicate pytest paramterize decorator behavior using pytest-case**

I've created a pytest framework to test an api. The test is to construct an api dynamically using different parameters from yaml file and execute it to check the status code.

first I have used pytest-cases to overcome the problem of using the fixture as an argument in parameterize decorator.
There is one pytest-case function written which has a read_file fixture injected. The fixture returns a list of tuple values generated from yaml.

when I ran the test I was expecting the test to be executed as many times as the length of list[tuple] but the test case ran only once.

How can I achieve this using pytest-case? Or is there a more elegant way in pytest to achieve this?

When I used @pytest.mark.paramterize() I was able to run the test 8 times.

How can I achieve this using pytest-case?

**Below is my code**

my yaml file

```
dummy.yaml 

domain:
    - foo
    - bar
department:
    - abc
    - xyz
location:
    - usa
    - can
```

based on the yaml there can be 2*2*2=8 unique combinations of API.My test framework

```
#conftest.py

@pytest_fixture(scope=function)
def read_file(request):str -> List[Tuple]:
    file_name = os.path.abspath(f'(request.function.__name__).yaml')
    return ReadData.read_yaml_file(file_name[5:]) 


## case function

class DummyCase:

    @case(tags='dummy')
    def case_dummy(read_file) -> List[Tuple]:
        return read_file

# test function

class TestDummy:
    
    @parametrize_with_cases('parameters',cases=DummyCase,has_tag='dummy')
    def test_dummy(self,parameters):
        api = construct_api(parameters)
        assert True
```

when I executed this read_file returned a list of Tuples of length 8 but the test_dummy executed only once.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

I solved this problem using one simple approach without calling fixture as below

```
# test function

class TestDummy:
    
    api_params = ReadData.read_yaml_file(file_name)
    @pytest_mark_parametrize('domain,department,location',api_params)
    def test_dummy(self,domain,department,location):
        api = construct_api(domain,department,location)
        assert True
```

so in this code I read the file before test and got the list of tuples and then used it as argvalues. I was able to execute the test 8 times, but using this approach I have to manually pass the file name for each test which I don't want. Hence I was trying to read the file using fixtures hence trying to use pytest-case.